# How to filter one collection by another?

Tags: filter, set, java-stream

There are 2 sets, the user has a lot of fields, but the necessary one is the departmentId, they also gave me an id array for deletion, and this and that Strig. How can you iterate over oldUser and leave only those users whose departmentId is in removeUserById? Below is the stream that I wrote But it does not work, all users go to the abс set without exceptions

```
Set<User> oldEmploee = userRepository.findAllByDepartmentId(departmentId);
Set<String> newEmploee = command.getEmployees();
Set<User> abc = oldEmploee.stream().filter(e -> !newEmploee.contains(e.getDepartmentId())).collect(Collectors.toSet());

abc.forEach(user -> user.setDepartmentId("3a9b4a8a-9e8c-4b72-b3cd-4e72090c259b"));
userRepository.saveAll(abc);
```

Comment: You can’t expect any reader to known the difference between *your* methods `getDepartmentId()` and `getId()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set<User> abc = oldEmploee.stream().filter(e -> newEmploee.contains(**e.getId()**)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```